# What did Black Widow mean about the rock in the Potomac?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, captain-america, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

During the hearing at the very end of Winter Soldier:

> **Hearing General**: Why haven't we yet heard from Captain Rogers?
>
> **Black Widow**: I don't know what there is left for him to say. I think the rock in the middle of the Potomac made his point fairly eloquently.

Wikipedia tells me that the Potomac is the river in Washington, so I'm guessing that's something related to all the water around the Triskelion?

Can anyone explain this line properly for me?

Comment: per the wiki *"The Triskelion was built along the Potomac River on Theodore Roosevelt Island as an enormous complex that occupied almost all of the island"*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line is WRECK, not ROCK.
At which point it's all completely clear :)

Comment: That would make sense.

Comment: Although I do like the idea that Steve composed a long and nuanced essay on the risks of corruption and overreach in covert government agencies, then carved it into a boulder and left that next to the smoking remains of the helicarrier.

Answer (score 15):

The Triskelion is indeed situated [in the middle of the Potomac River](http://www.npr.org/sections/monkeysee/2014/04/01/297704279/captain-america-on-the-potomac) in the movie, specifically on [Theodore Roosevelt Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_Roosevelt_Island). My read on the lines is it's referring to the Triskelion having been destroyed by the falling helicarrier. SHIELD is effectively destroyed at this point and Black Widow is indicating that Captain America is moving forward.

[image: The Triskelion in the Potomac]